# How to send individual messages using ZMQ efficiently in both python and php

Tags: php, python, sockets, zeromq, pyzmq

I currently have a PHP function:

```
function sendLocalSocket($message, $port){
    $context = new ZMQContext();
    $socket = $context->getSocket(ZMQ::SOCKET_PUSH);
    $socket->connect("tcp://127.0.0.1:$port");
    $socket->send($message);
}
```

and a python function:

```
def create_local_socket(port, pull=False):
    context = zmq.Context()
    if pull:
        # for receiving socket messages
        socket = context.socket(zmq.PULL)
        socket.bind("tcp://127.0.0.1:%d" % port)
    else:
        # for sending socket messages
        socket = context.socket(zmq.PUSH)
        socket.connect("tcp://127.0.0.1:%d" % port)
    return socket
```

<sub>which then sends a message with `create_local_socket(port).send_json()`</sub>

Unfortunately either of these two functions when called in quick succession start to hang dramatically and slow down the rest of my system.

I have been thinking of ways to keep the sockets open for the never terminating python script but unfortunately for PHP this is called after a file upload.

The problem is that these functions are called arbitrarily - the php script uses the same port each upload but the python script uses different ports (although there is repeated use).

I know that the php is hanging because the python ZMQ listener logs the `current time - the time the file was uploaded` which takes longer and longer until the backlog of uploads dies down. I also know that the listener script is not hanging and takes 0.2 seconds after logging receiving the file. (but that is effectively a back log!)

I feel like the answer is to persist these connections.

---

## Edit 1:

Trying: `$context = new ZMQContext(1, true);` did not help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given each call to either of the code-snippets generates another **`Context()`**-instance, this constitutes rather an anti-pattern for a reasonable use of resources.

A mild read about Zen-of-Zero will soon show the main reasons, why building a (semi-)persistent signalling / messaging layer is the way to go, as the resources allocations / deallocations are always expensive plus leaving so many un-terminated instances will soon deplete any amount of resources available.

ZeroMQ tools are far from being used as a one-shot disposable. Efficiency goes hand in hand with minimised resources-related overheads, so indeed best to re-design the ad-hoc creation of never deallocated resources pools and rather prepare all the needed tools before these need to be already active and ready to serve an ad-hoc request.

A due re-factoring of the Product has high time to take place.

---

While [documentation reports](https://github.com/mkoppanen/php-zmq/wiki/Persistent-context---socket) some persistence aided modus-operandi, one ought carefully review its costs/benefits before going into this direction, as Zen-of-Zero is actually considering any sort of sharing a rather anti-pattern for [distributed-system](/questions/tagged/distributed-system) design practices, plus warns on:

### Note

It’s important to remember that careless use of persistent sockets **can exhaust** available file-handles on the machine.

```
function sendLocalSocket( $message,                 //  IS to be get delivered
                          $port                     // WAS reported to be
                          ){                        //     all the time the same 
    $context = new ZMQContext( 2, true );           // MAY try persistent CTX
    $socket = $context->getSocket( ZMQ::SOCKET_PUSH,
                                  "persistLoggerID" // MAY use persistent SOCK
                                   );
    $socket->connect(    "tcp://127.0.0.1:$port" ); // MAY use less expensive TC
    $socket->send(       $message,
                          ZMQ::MODE_NOBLOCK         // USE non-blocking mode
                          );
    $socket->disconnect( "tcp://127.0.0.1:$port" ); // USE .disconnect()
}
```

---

### Final note

Quality, robustness and performance of any application depends on how well the language and the language-specific ZeroMQ-binding can respect the native API and reflect the best-practices evolved for using the native DLL-services. Any "abstraction" and/or "automated" steps, that reduce the designer's control over the scope and ordering of otherwise due steps on the native-API level may look comfortable, yet these also reduce the options for designing robust and high-performance deployments, as some native-API tweaking options need not be principally available at the user-application level, once having been shaded-out by language-specific ZeroMQ-binding abstractions.

Comment: I completely agree but my system is very "one-shot" by definition. Correct me if I am wrong but I really can't see any way to do this with a PHP $_FILE upload script? I have this sort of techniques implemented in many different projects :| (Just the PHP)

Comment: My technique to fix the above at the moment is to just rate limit the uploads. (max 1 upload every 0.5 seconds)

Comment: Thank you for such a brilliant answer. I don't quite understand `persistent_id` does this mean that if I set the label in `getSocket` and then use `getSocket` again in a completely different php thread with the label it will acquire the persistent socket? Also I thought that the socket was disconnected when the object dies at the end of the php script - https://github.com/mkoppanen/php-zmq/issues/153 ? I am also guessing the `MODE_NOBLOCK` prevents the disconnect from killing the send?

Comment: `MODE_NOBLOCK ` is [depreciated](http://php.net/manual/en/class.zmq.php#zmq.constants.mode-noblock) `MODE_DONTWAIT` should be used.

Comment: Header files typically keep definitions for both ( often via sort of chained aliases ) **`DONTWAIT`** and **`NOBLOCK`**, so this is more a matter of taste and evangelisation of non-functional changes than anything important ... **:o)**

Comment: **Persistence** is a `php`-specific behaviour, not present in the native-API, so more attention and care ought be paid here. As only very briefly mentioned in the php-specific language binding, the `persistence_ID` ought map the generated object into some global dictionary of **`"zeromq_socket:[<ZmqSockTYPE>]-[<persistenceID>]"`**, which seems to be maintained under the hood of the semi-persistent `php::ZMQ::ZMQContext` instance, if all goes well. While such features were mentioned, more details ought be sought in the source files, as this is not a native-API modus-operandi, so ask PHP-sources

Comment: **Disconnect**: means ZMTP release. Scheduled messages ought remain inside the **`ZMQ::ZMQContext`** instance's respective internal Queues until delivered ( they do not get dispatched right at the moment of `.send()`-method request has returned back, one may test this feature ). All ZeroMQ operations are asynchronous, which means that `ZMQ::ZMQContext`-instance decides when and how things happen to move through the live transport-class path(s). Native ZeroMQ APIs explicitly recommend "manual" resources management, not relying on any deferred scope-end/deferred destructor invocation mechanics

Comment: Can you remove "see Learn more..." from your edit on https://stackoverflow.com/tags/nanomsg/info?

Comment: @Cœur could you kindly advise me where is such an edit-tool available? The proposal seems to me to be inside some approval pipeline, where I see no revise options yet. Are there any such? And what is your kind rationale for proposing a reference to follow a StackOverflow's own **"see [tag:Learn more ..]"** for extended learning materials is better be rather avoided, if you meant to do this?

Comment: It may be that someone already voted to approved/reject your suggested edit, so maybe you can't modify it anymore for this review.

Comment: @user3666197 any ideas with: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49634747/implementing-a-local-socket-to-send-message-over-web-socket-arbitrarily ?